# Android JNI conflicts with Java JNI Specification

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, dalvik, art-runtime

According to Java JNI Specification [Native Method Arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#wp715):

> The JNI interface pointer is the first argument to native methods. The
>   JNI interface pointer is of type JNIEnv. The **second argument** differs
>   depending on whether the native method is static or nonstatic. The
>   second argument to a nonstatic native method is a reference to the
>   object. The second argument to a static native method is a reference
>   to its Java class.

So a native function implementation should contains at least two local argument：first is **JNIEnv**, second is **jobject** or **jclass**, but in android framework there are many codes conflits with these rule, for example:

android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/cd92588/media/java/android/media/MediaScanner.java#1822

```
private static native final void native_init();
```

android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/media/jni/android_media_MediaScanner.cpp#375

```
static void android_media_MediaScanner_native_init(JNIEnv *env)
{
    ALOGV("native_init");
    jclass clazz = env->FindClass(kClassMediaScanner);
    if (clazz == NULL) {
        return;
    }

  fields.context = env->GetFieldID(clazz, "mNativeContext", "J");
    if (fields.context == NULL) {
        return;
    }
}
```

function registe:

```
{
    "native_init",
    "()V",
    (void *)android_media_MediaScanner_native_init
},
```

android_media_MediaScanner_native_init only receive one argument, so is there any dalvik or art runtime tricks or other reason？

Comment: That looks like bad code to me.  It appears to be relying on the platform's calling convention to get away with omitting the `jclass` argument to `android_media_MediaScanner_native_init()`.  It also seems to make little sense - the code attempts to locate a class using `kClassMediaScanner`. Assuming that's the `MediaScanner` class that this code is a member of, extra code had to be written to cache a value *that the JVM passes*.

Comment: somebody left a comment, but the comment disappeared, i don't know why, original comment is: it much like this [link](https://pastebin.com/70Up22Hc)

Comment: @AndrewHenle thanks.